# Interface and Abstract class share same method

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

Is this design really valid?
Legacy application code, so just trying to refactor if it's not necessary.

```
public interface Interface { 
public void abc();
}

public abstract class abClass implements Interface{
@Override
public void abc(){
throw new UnsupportedOpException(NOT_IMPLEMENTED_MSG);
}

public class xyz extends abClass{
@Override
public void abc(){
.......//some code here

}
```

Can I get rid of the `Interface`?  Not sure what's the original intention was behind this design. When would you want to have `same methods` in both `interface` and `abstract` classes which gets eventually `overriden`?

Comment: Its actually good practise to use interfaces like this. Look up some info on interfaces.

Comment: Good practise ???? For API classes yes, otherwise, just overhead.

Comment: @davidhxxx That's exactly I was thinking too..

Comment: I did a response to develop. It's not white or black :)

Comment: It is a good practice. All classes are API classes. Some are internal to a project, some are external is the only difference. Unless you don't design them well, in which case they might not be API classes. Of course, a good practice doesn't necessarily mean "use it everywhere all the time".

Answer (score 0):

`void abc();` must be implemented either by the abstract class or by the inherited classes...

there is no chance to get rid off that...

if you prefer, you can move the  void abc(); as a method of the Abstract class...

redefined it and:

- Block the overriding of ot by making it final.

or

- delegate the responsability of the implementation to child classes by making it abstract too..

Comment: That's my question, even if I remove the Interface and remove  'implements interface' in the abstract class , it doesn't break the code. So why cant I just define it under the abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

I think, from a functional programming perspective, it's fine as is. Having `implements Interface` just means the class must *have* a method with the same name. The fact that it is defined in `abClass` means that not only are you saying that all classes that inherit from `abClass` must have the interface, but also that you don't need to redefine it in every class, unless you wish to override.

So you don't actually define the method in `Interface`, but you do in `abClass`, and when you define the method in `xyz`, you're overriding the method in `abClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But why can't I just get rid of the interface? As long as  the abstract class provides the method definition, its inherited/overridden(if required) by child classes.

Comment: You totally could. But what if you wanted to define another class and also have it have a method that does something like what `abc()` does? And since its a different kind of object, it doesn't make sense to have it inherit whatever other methods are in `abClass`. You could simply say `implements Interface`, and it would have to have `abc()`.

Comment: Example: Interface: `IShape` has the method `public void area(int base, int height)`. You have abstract class `Quadrilateral`(with `area(int base, int height)` defined), and child classes `Square`(which overrides the area method) and `Rectangle`(which keeps the area method). But you want to create another class, `Triangle`, and it doesn't make sense to have it inherit Quadrilateral's method, since it'll be slightly different anyways. So have `class Triangle implements IShape` will allow you to define a method called area.

Comment: You could just have Triangle have another method with the same name, but atleas this way you can create objects like: `IShape tri = new Triangle()` and `IShape sq = new Square()` and by default, they recognize themselves as IShape objects, and so must have an area method.

Comment: I got your point and I agree. But in my case, only abClass implements the Interface and all other classes extends the abClass. So the interface is not used anywhere at all but the abClass. Hence I felt like redundant code as the abstract class doesn't have any logic for those Interface methods and have the concrete classes comes up with their own logic. I agree if there is another class than implements Interface directly, then it can stay. if not why extra code(just to enforce the contract)?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, and you could just leave it out. It does seem like extra code; honestly it's good programming practice, and usually that just means a bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

An Interface should be used behind an abstract class when it offers something you need and that an abstract class cannot offer.
 
Create an interface for no concrete reasons but because you think that `interface==OOP` brings overhead and proves that you misunderstand what OOP is.

In your case, if in the applicative code, you notice that you can remove the interface behind the abstract class and that you have no real impact at compile time, you may wonder if the abstraction of the interface is not just an overhead. It may be useful as not useful. I will develop it.

Using an interface behind a abstract class opens implementation possibilities : you may benefit of this abstract class related with the interface but you can also implement the interface in concrete classes without benefiting of the abstract class, therefore as you wish. Writing an implementation from A to Z may be suitable as not suitable according to our needs.

Personally, I think that the interface is useful behind an abstract class in two cases :

- the interface is common for at all types of target concrete classes but the 
  abstract class is relevant not for all types of target concrete classes.

For example when you implement a decorator, you have a common interface to represent both decorated classes and decorator classes. 
The decorator classes have different logic and data from the decorated classes. So, our abstract class for decorator classes or for decorated classes may be different.

Here an simple example to represent Decorator for document.

Common interface :

```
public interface IDocumentInput {

    void read();

    byte[] getBytes();

    String getStringContent();

}
```

decorated document :

```
public class DocumentInput implements IDocumentInput {

    private byte[] bytes;

    public DocumentInput(byte[] bytes) {
      this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
      return bytes;
    }

    public void read() {
    }

    public String getStringContent() {
      return new String(getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

}
```

abstract class for decorators :

```
public abstract class AbstractDocumentInputDecorator implements IDocumentInput {

    protected IDocumentInput document;
    protected byte[] bytes;

    public AbstractDocumentInputDecorator(IDocumentInput document) {
      this.document = document;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
      return bytes;
    }

    public final String getStringContent() {
      return new String(getBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Concrete decorator :

```
public class SecuredDocumentInputDecorator extends AbstractDocumentInputDecorator {

    public SecuredDocumentInputDecorator(IDocumentInput document) {
      super(document);
    }

    @Override
    public void read() {
      document.read();
      processUnsecuring();
    }

    private void processUnsecuring() {
      byte[] originalBytes = document.getBytes();
      bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(originalBytes);
    }

}
```

In this case, it seems logical to introduce an interface because the abstract class is not enough to represent common behavior and or data of all concrete classes.

- You want to provide to developers the possibility to create their own implementation of the interface with or without relying on the abstract class implementation. In general, it's desirable when you create an open API.
  Collections in JDK classes illustrate very well that.
  Indeed, if you want to create interface/contract promoting extensibility, when you provide only an abstract class, developers which want to create their implementation are forced to use the abstract class even if they don't want. Which is not desirable.
- You use a library which forces you to use interfaces. For example with EJB 3.0 and Spring in these first versions, using abstract class or class doesn't allow  to benefit from some of their features.